# Issue with the way my site looks in IE8 compatibility view

Tags: css, html, ie8-compatibility-mode

I'll try to make this as simple as possible. I'm working on a site right now which you can see at http://wordpress.myecsinc.com. Keep in mind this is a TEST site and it is not done, that being said theres a lot of errors here and there but I plan on fixing it all.

Anyhow, when I check out the site in IE8 compatibility view, two of the images at the bottom end up smushed together (so to speak). When I get out of compatibility view it looks just as it should. Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this and how I could fix it?

I tried to attach a screenshot but it won't let me since I'm new to this site. Just open up the site in IE8 and switch to compatibility view and you'll see what I mean.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left image has the following css class which is causing the issue:

```
.index-nav-img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

If the class is removed then the alignment is fixed. Is there some reason for this class to be on the first image and not the others?

Note I tested this in firefox.

Comment: Wow, I'm a complete idiot... I don't know why I had that class on the first image alone but I took it off. That seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Just used firebug to find what was wrong. Edited out the class and it fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, I must have been working on this for so long that I overlooked something so simple! Sometimes it just takes another person looking at it to point out the obvious!

Answer (score 2):

Use the appropriate meta tags to force IE out of compatibility mode and not have to worry about this problem. The appropriate tag is:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a good solution I was not aware of.

Comment: If this is the solution, then what was the problem? I thought you were testing how your site looked in IE7.